# How to do player input validation with different classes

Tags: java, validation

Game.java

```
public void getLetter() {
    System.out.print("Give a letter: ");
    guessedLetter = ((PlayerHuman) player1).letterGuessing();   
    }   
}
```

PlayerHuman.java

```
public char letterGuessing() {
    inputString = scanner.nextLine();
    if(inputString.isEmpty()) {
        //need code here, also check if its only a-z
    }
    inputChar = inputString.toUpperCase().charAt(0);
    return inputChar;
}
```

I  have this code. In the `getLetter()` it asks for a letter and then it calls the `letterGuessing()` method. In the `letterGuessing()` method it needs to check if the input is not empty and only a letter in the alphabet before returning the letter.

If it's empty or not a letter it needs to do the whole `getLetter()` method again. Like ask for a new letter with that syso.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following logic :

```
public char letterGuessing() {
    String inputString;
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Give a letter: ");
        inputString = scanner.nextLine();
        if (inputString != null && inputString.length() > 0 && Character.isLetter(inputString.charAt(0))) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return inputString.toUpperCase().charAt(0);
}
```

Here, the `while-loop` is  not broken until and unless the `inputString` provided is a letter. There are additional checks to prior to that in the `if` to avoid any `NPE`'s.

Also, I have moved the line `System.out.print("Give a letter: ");` into the method `letterGuessing()` for better understand-ability.

You could tweak that accordingly.

Comment: Ah yes, this works exactly as I wanted it. Thanks a lot man :)